# Error while provisioning Azure resources with Terraform using Azure Services

Tags: azure, terraform

My code to create a Terraform configuration.

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resource-group"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "example" {
  name                        = "example-nsg-rule"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "22"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.example.name
}
```

My error here is

> Error: Error creating/updating Network Security Rule
> "example-nsg-rule" (Resource Group "example-resource-group"):
> network.SecurityRulesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidRequestFormat"
> Message="Cannot parse the request." Details=[{"Message":"The request
> body is invalid. Please provide a valid request body."}]

I suspect there might be an issue with the configuration or a missing parameter.
Could someone please review the code and provide insights into the error?

Comment: please provide `azurerm_resource_group ` and `azurerm_network_security_group ` resources.

Comment: I am able to execute your code without any errors. Which Terraform and AzureRM versions are you running? Are you deploying new resources or trying to modify existing ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I Tried to provision the resources with terraform using the following code and was able to provision the resources without any issues with some changes in the code.

Based on the error message provided, there might be an issue with the request body for the network security rule. Upon reviewing the `destination_Address_prefixes` parameter in the `azurerm_security_rule resource` block this parameter specifies the destination IP address range for the network security rule.

To overcome this we need to specify the destination_address_prefixes parameter with a valid IP address range.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
 features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name = "v-bolliv"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet"{
  name                = "demovk-vnet"
  address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet' {
  name = "demosubnetvk"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  virtual network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestSecurityGroup1"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "example" {
  name                        = "demovk1901"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "*"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefixes  = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.example.name
}
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]